# My mac is blocking all dylib used by STM32CubeIde

Tags: macos, stm32, stm32cubeide

When I try to Debug on `STM32CubeIde` my mac blocks the `dylib` it use, I go to preferences and security and allow it to run, but there are so many `dylib` and the Debug mode fails

[image: Error on STM32CubeIde]

[image: Mac Error]

[image: Allow anyway on Mac preferences]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem.
When an Application blocks dylib you can try this:

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

on Terminal.
Then go to settings->Privacy and click on allow apps downloaded from any site.
Then restart the STM32CubeIDE and it works on Debug mode.

Does STM32CubeIDE keep working if you reenable Gatekeeper afterwards?
Answering this question: Once you close the IDE, the Gatekeeper reenables automatically.
If not, the command is

```
sudo spctl --master-enable
```

Comment: While this may solve the problem, it disables an important security feature of macOS. Does STM32CubeIDE keep working if you reenable Gatekeeper afterwards? If it does, it might be nice to mention this (as well as the command for reenabling Gatekeeper) so that other users who come across your post do not unnecessarily compromise the security of their computer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).